# JAX-RS Auto marshalling List<Object> to JSON

Tags: java, json, rest

I am using Glassfish 3 which uses the Jersey Implementation for JAX-RS. I have the following method REST endpoint:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<CourseDTO> listAll() {

    List<CourseDTO> list = findAll();


    return list;
}
```

My CourseDTO is the following:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CourseDTO implements Serializable {


    private long courseId;
    private String courseName;


    public CourseDTO() {

    }
     //getters setters
}
```

The JSON object I get back is the following:

```
  {
      "courseDTO":
           [
              {"courseId":"1","courseName":"C++"},
              {"courseId":"2","courseName":"Java"}
           ]
   }
```

However, ideally I would want the following:

```
[
    {"courseId":"1","courseName":"C++"},
    {"courseId":"2","courseName":"Java"}
]
```

So basically I want to get rid of the "wrapper" object. Is there someway to do it or should I have to do manual marshalling?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16614455/1817029

Comment: Try using [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/), you just need it on your classpath to enable json support with it. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/JaxbBundle) are the JAXB annotations actually supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Google Gson library. The code is as simple as :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CourseDTO >>() {
                    }.getType();
 List<CourseDTO > courses = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```